# Windows Shell Extension dll and Winform process

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-shell

I made a dll for  Windows Shell Extension integration, following this tutorial http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx[^]

Now, I added a Windows form in that dll, I'm doing the following:

```
void OnVerbDisplayFileName(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    ShowSelectedFiles form = new ShowSelectedFiles();
    form.Show(selectedFiles);
}
```

Everything works fine, just the Forms icon is not shown in task bar and I can't find the process that runs my form.

Any tip on how to solve this problem? Maybe by starting a new process and then showing the form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve this is to create another process.

```
    void OnVerbDisplayFileName(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        string file = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
        string executableName = file.Substring(0, file.LastIndexOf("/"));
        executableName += "/MyApp.exe";

        Process gui = new Process();

        gui.StartInfo.FileName = executableName;
        gui.StartInfo.Arguments = selectedFiles.JoinFileNames(" ");

        gui.Start();
    }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Form.Show Method (IWin32Window)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) method so that you can specify the owner window.

See http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/23/465.aspx for how to specify the owner window from an hWnd.

Also make sure that the form's ShowInTaskBar property is true.

Comment: I tried but it isn't working in this case. See my proposed solution. However, thanks!